# Date filtering in PySpark using between

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, filter, between

I have a Spark dataframe with date columns. The "date1col" last entry is today and the "date2col" has the last entry of 10 days ago. I need to filter the dates for the last two weeks up to yesterday.

I used `df.filter(col('date1col').between(current_date()-1,current_date()-15)`, and it worked fine. However, when I used the same syntax for the second date column, i.e.: `df.filter(col('date2col').between(current_date()-1,current_date()-15)` , it returned an empty sdf. When I used `df.filter(col('startdate')>current_date()-15)`, it worked. But my dataframe is dynamic, meaning it updates daily at 9am. How can I force the `between` function to return the same sdf like I am using the `>` logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the order:
first - earlier date
second - later date

```py
df.filter(col('date2col').between(current_date()-15, current_date()-1))
```

*They are not the same*, it can be proved using [**`sameSemantics`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sameSemantics.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sameSemantics)

```py
df1 = df.filter(col('date2col').between(current_date()-15, current_date()-1))
df2 = df.filter(col('date2col').between(current_date()-1, current_date()-15))
df1.sameSemantics(df2)
# False
```

---

If you still need - `.between` translated to "<>" logic:

`df.filter(col('date2col').between(current_date()-15, current_date()-1))`
=
`df.filter((col('date2col') >= current_date()-15) & (col('date2col') <= current_date()-1))`

```py
df1 = df.filter(col('date2col').between(current_date()-15, current_date()-1))
df2 = df.filter((col('date2col') >= current_date()-15) & (col('date2col') <= current_date()-1))

print(df1.sameSemantics(df2)) # `True` when the logical query plans are equal, thus same results
# True
```

---

"<>" translated to `.between`

`df.filter(col('date2col') > current_date()-15)`
= `df.filter(col('date2col').between(current_date()-14, '9999'))`

`sameSemantics` result would apparently be `False`, but for any practical case, results would be same.